# Confused about static class vars in python

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, static-variables

Here a little example code:

```
class A:
    staticvar=3;

    def foo2(self):
        print("------ Foo2")
        print("static: "+str(A.staticvar));
        print("instance: "+ str(self.staticvar));

class B(A):

    def setStaticVar(self, num):
        B.staticvar=num;


a=A();
b=B();

a.staticvar=7;
a.foo2();

b.setStaticVar(100);

a.foo2();

b.foo2();
```

what results in:

```
------ 
static: 3
instance: 7  -->correct. Instance var modified
------ 
static: 3
instance: 7  --> Not correct. Why static var is not 100
------ 
static: 3
instance: 100 --> Correct, but this value should be shared between A and B
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the static variable be shared between A and B? Why when it is modified in b through b.

From this example it seems, each class has its own static var (not really static from my point of view because there would only be one static var and we have 2, one per class).

Could anyone explain this behaviour?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what you're running into is an issue of name resolution. When you get `B.staticvar`, the interpreter fails to find it and falls back on its super classes to try to resolve the name. Upon traversing to `A`, the interpreter finds `staticvar` and returns the value.

When you set a value to `B.staticvar`, however, you get much the same behavior as your "instance" case, where a *new* property called `staticvar` is added to `B`. Now, when it attempts to resolve the property name on `B` (or instances thereof), it uses this new value without ever falling back to `A`. In Python, inheriting a class isn't much about sharing its properties, it's about setting a fallback class to resolve names when they aren't defined in your child class (hence why there's no need to explicitly "override" methods, and why you must remember to call `super(A).method_name` within `B.method_name` if you want the parent function to be run).

To get the behavior you're asking for, either define `setStaticVar` in `A`, and/or change its body to `A.staticvar=num`

Comment: And how is it, that the class having only a static var can be accesed through A.staticvar or self.staticvar inside the class? Shouldn't it throw an error when using print(self.staticvar) because it can't resolve the instance var?

Comment: Name resolution on a class instance starts on the instance, but then backs onto the class itself. For example, the methods of a class are defined on the class, not its instances, but you can call them on an instance. For example, given `a = A()`, `a.setStaticVar(5)` resolves to `A.setStaticVar(a, 5)`, and in fact you can just write that second line and it'll behave exactly the same. Likewise, `staticvar` exists in `A`, can be accessed by `a`, or can be shadowed by defining a property of `a` with the same name.

Comment: In general, in a dynamically typed language like Python (and I believe the same holds largely true for JS and similar languages), think of "classes" and "instances" purely in terms of mappings of names to values with a tree of backups that you can go to should the name not resolve at any given point. Objects, types, modules, and even local contexts (closures) are all just dictionaries that can nest within each other. You can play games to modify those dictionaries at various levels, but there isn't much idea of "static" variables in such a language.